# Solving Differential equation on variable separation can't solve please help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I can't it don't know where am I being wrong. I wasn't able to separate variables or make to a linear form and it isn't even homogeneous and I can't think of any substitution that would help me solve this can someone please help me with this question

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(x+y)^2}{(x+2)(y-2)}$$

My approach= $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(x+y+2-2)^2}{(x+2)(y-2)}$$
            $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(x+2)^2}{(x+2)(y-2)} + \frac{(y-2)^2}{(x+2)(y-2)} + \frac{2(x+2)(y-2)}{(x+2)(y-2)}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{(x+2)}{(y-2)}+\frac{(y-2)}{(x+2)}+2$$

Now I can't figure out how to solve it please help

Comment: Try $u=y-2$, $v=x+2$.

Comment: If I face a problem on a certain question and want to ask it so it matches the standard of this forum? Can u please help me with it kinda new here

Comment: Two advices: *the first one* is to have a look at the [basic Math Jax syntax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). This will help you in producing nicely formatted mathematical texts, improving the understandability (and the beauty) of your posts. The *second advice* is to provide a little context for your question: is it an exercise or something else? What did you tried in order to solve the it? And you may add any othe observation which may help other members help you.

Comment: I did the edits you suggested is anything else needed?

Comment: At this stage of insight, you can just set $u=\frac{y-2}{x+2}$ to get $y'=(x+2)u'+u=u+u^{-1}+2$ which is separable.

Comment: Hey, aditya! How you doin?

Comment: Good what about you

Comment: I am doing fine. You are in CMI, right?

Comment: Nope I'm not actually my its my 12th standard

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you were this Aditya Prakash(https://www.imo-official.org/participant_r.aspx?id=27459).

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Make the change of variables

$$
u = x+2\\
v = y-2
$$

giving

$$
\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{(u+v)^2}{u v}
$$

and then $v = \lambda u$ arriving into a separable DE.

$$
\frac{d\lambda}{\frac{1}{\lambda} + 2} = \frac{du}{u}
$$

Comment: Yup it's solved didn't thought it that way thanks you were a great help